# Solving Transcendental Equations

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving, mapthread

I want to solve the transcendental equations as follows

$$ A=\frac{w^{\frac{b}{a}}}{c^{\frac{2}{a}}}\mid cos(\frac{b\pi}{2a})\mid $$
$$ c=\frac{c^{\frac{2}{a}}}{w^{\frac{b}{a}-1}}\mid csc(\frac{b\pi}{2a})\mid $$

A, w, c are variable coefficients from the files, which is not given, but I give three data, see the codes. a, b are to be solved. Here is my codes:

```
% this is the import codes
w = Import["D:\\K-K relations\\omega_result.csv"];
c = Import["D:\\K-K relations\\wave_velocity_2_result.csv"];
A = Import["D:\\K-K relations\\attenuation_2_result.csv"];

% this is the input codes
w = {1244070.6908, 1250353.8761, 1256637.0614};
c = {6392.5049, 6392.2376, 6391.9549};
A = {4.7440, 4.8222, 4.9010};

% this is the calculation
FindInstance[{A == w^(b/a)*Abs[Cos[b*Pi/(2*a)]]/c^(2/a), 
  c == c^(2/a)*Abs[Csc[b*Pi/(2*a)]]/w^(b/a - 1), 0 < a <= 2, 
  0 < b <= 2}, {a, b}]
```

If w,c,a contains one element, this code can be calculated, but if w,c,a contains more than two elements, this code is running all the time. So how to solve this problem? Or any alternative methods to solve the equations?

Comment: sorry to the edit this question. If w,c,a is changed w,c,A.

Comment: Don't post unsearchable images of equations.  Instead typeset in *MathJax*.

Comment: Thanks for David's suggestion.

Comment: I'm glad you understand the "suggestion" and why it is the requirement of this site.  Now *make the changes*!!!

Comment: Sorry, I tried to use the MathJax, but I don't know how to insert this page.

Comment: Try typing $A = \frac{x}{y}$ (\frac{x}{y} surrounded by dollar signs) into your question.  Then expand from there.

Comment: Thank you! I have tried to do it and succeed!

Comment: Multiply the two equations and solve for b/a.  Divide the two equations and solve for a.  You will get an analytic solution.  You will need to specify conditions for the other constants to narrow the possibilities.  I can't do it for you because the question is closed.

Answer (score 1):

```
MapThread[
 FindInstance[{#3 == #1^(b/a)*
      Abs[Cos[b*Pi/(2*a)]]/#2^(2/a), #2 == #2^(2/a)*
      Abs[Csc[b*Pi/(2*a)]]/#1^(b/a - 1), 0 < a <= 2, 0 < b <= 2}, {a, 
    b}] &,
 {w, c, A}]
```

> {{{a -> 0.0237378, b -> 1.25773}}, {{a -> 0.0246518,     b ->
> 1.25763}}, {{a -> 0.0237209, b -> 1.25683}}}

Comment: Thanks. Your code can be calculated. I tried to calculate from the import files, but when the data is large, the calculation is running for a long time. So, do you have any methods to improve the calculation efficiency?

Comment: `large` is a relative concept. You can write a function wrapper providing `w`, `c`, `A` to each invocation but the heart of the problem would still reduce to improving the speed of `FindInstance` and that depends on the complexity of the equations. If you post a new question that is specifically about the speed up for this particular set of equations, someone might be able to suggest a better alternative. Make sure you mention how big the value of `large` is.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.